# Can list messages but cant create subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have an app that creates subscriptions for office365 users and does something whenever it gets a notification.

For 99% of users it works fine.

There's one user that I can't create subscription for even though he has an enabled exchange plan.
When I try to create subscription for him I get status code `404` and message: `REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox`.

However, I can list the user messages (i.e. mails) with API (GET request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/{user_id}/messages`)

Is it normal behavior? That user have no rest services enables for his mailbox (and therefore cant create subscription) but other rest services such as listing messages works just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely getting this error because the organization has an hybrid deployment (Exchange on prem "linked" to the organization) and the mailbox that's failing is located on premises, not in the cloud.

Your application should handle the error and/or let the administrators know that this mailbox is failing, but there isn't much that can be done besides migrating the mailbox. [For reference](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/REST-API-is-not-yet-supported-for-this-mailbox/m-p/122153#M25477)

Comment: Ok, and are you sure that having this one mailbox on premises, will still allow listing its messages? only notifications mechanism requires cloud?

Comment: It could be the case if this is deployed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support you should confirm with the administrator though

Comment: Cool. Thank you!